# How to redefine the sorting of product categories by menu_order?

Tags: categories, woocommerce-offtopic, order, sort

With the help of elementor and jetengine from crocoblock, I display product categories. These categories are sorted by the date they were added, but I would like them to be displayed in the order in which they are located in the admin panel. How can this be done using the can function of some kind?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Probably, but you might do better asking Elementary or Croco Black about this: I don't know either set of code so I've no idea how they order product categories.